# Redirect with multiple mapped domains (htaccess and WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mapping

We have a web portal for multiple countries. Each country has its own domain (i.e. countrydomain.com, countrydomain.de, countrydomain.it). 
 All of these country domains are mapped to our main domain (maindomain.org) with symlinks. The main domain holds the whole PHP code for the web portal. The .htaccess manages the redirections for all domains.

This works so far...

Now, I have to create a WordPress blog for each country which should be reachable under countrydomain.com/blog, countrydomain.de/blog an so on. Each country should have its own blog with its own content.

My problem is, that I can't create a "blog" directory for each country and just install Wordpress in this directory because of the mapping. I have only our maindomain.org.
I have tried to create directories named blog_com, blog_de, blog_it and redirect them with htaccess to the matching domain/blog, but with no success so far...

Is it best practice to create one wordpress-folder for each country? Which redirect rules do I need to manage the redirects? Or is there an even better solution?

Here comes a part of our htaccess to show you the current situation:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Enforce www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]

# Skip some directories
RewriteRule ^newsletter$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^newsletter/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^cron/.*$ - [L]


# Rewrite main domain to main country domain (com)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.maindomain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.countrydomain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

# Save current top level domain as environment variable
SetEnvIf Host ^www\.countrydomain\.com$ ENV_COUNTRYCODE=com
SetEnvIf Host ^www\.countrydomain\.de$ ENV_COUNTRYCODE=de
SetEnvIf Host ^www\.countrydomain\.it$ ENV_COUNTRYCODE=it

# SEO rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?status=19 [L]
RewriteRule ^myprofile$ index.php?status=50 [L]
RewriteRule ^myprofile/$ index.php?status=50 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(xx)/([A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ\%\+\_\-\/]{3,100}).html$ index.php?status=90&xxurl=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ\%\+\_\/\-]{3,300})/([0-9]+)(b|bw)$ index.php?status=25&id=$2&type=bw [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(b|bw)$ index.php?status=25&id=$1&type=bw [QSA,L]
# ...
```

Comment: Have you considered WP Multisite with mapped domains?

Comment: @b__ Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I have considered WP Multisite. But if I install WP with Multisite enabled in the directory maindomain.org/wordpress/ and go to the network setup in the Wordpress backend, Wordpress tells me, that my network address will be "maindomain.org"... (not "maindomain.org/wordpress). I do not dare to install this network, because I'm not sure, whether the rest of the web portal will run properly after I have set up the wordpress Multisite... Unfortunately I can't test this in a simmilar test environment.

Comment: Yep, your current setup is quite complex, I suppose adding MS would be a chirurgical movement.

Comment: @b__ So, do you see a possible solution without multisite?